# Fastest way to search through a CSV and return specific array of values (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv

Basically, I would like to search through a CSV that I read in. It will be read in as an array of arrays. I want to extract only the rows where the first element of the row is equal to a certain value. If this is true, I want to then extract the row as a unit and add it to an array for further data processing.

Right now, I am using

```
CSV.foreach(filepath) do |row|
  if (row[0] == experiment)
    exp1 = true && (row[0] == experiment) && row[7] == data)
    if exp1
      exp1_array.push(row)
    end
  end
end
```

What is currently happening is that it is way too slow, because the CSV is a huge file. I was wondering if anyone had a really quick way to read through a CSV, check for conditions, and add to a specific array if those conditions are true.

Also, I need to add to exp1_array if the first row says the name of experiment1, and then add to exp2_array if the first row says the name of experiment2, so that is why the first if conditional check exists.

If anyone could help I would be immensely grateful!!

Comment: Huge files are going to be slow. Define "huge" and define "slow", though. There's no heavy computing going on here so there's no easy way to fix this. Maybe you could pre-filter your CSV file somehow?

Comment: what is `experiment`? Is it a variable or a method call?

Comment: yeah, i think i'm looking to pre-filter my CSV, just want to know some method that could help me do so?

Comment: experiment is a variable, the name of the string I want to match

Comment: If you're doing this more than once then load the CSV into a database (using the database's native CSV loader), index it to support your queries, and then query it using the database.

Comment: I agree with @muistooshort although given the nature of this being a CSV file and not having any relational need maybe try a NoSQL Database like Mongo. [Example of Loading a CSV in Mongo](http://mensfeld.pl/2012/10/using-mongodb-to-store-and-retrieve-csv-files-content-in-ruby/) or Couch [1](https://blog.couchbase.com/bulk-loading-documents-into-couchbase), [2](https://github.com/wbzyl/nosql-tutorial/blob/master/pp/ruby/csv/csv2couch.rb) if you prefer

Comment: @engineersmnky : Yes, [MongoDB is web-scale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2F-DItXtZs) ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil: That is great I hadn't seen that before thank you for the laugh. I have had this argument recently with a colleague regarding firebase and how it is "Web Scale" and "Real Time". (Disclaimer: NoSQL database can have a place if used correctly) ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using a NoSQL database like suggested in comments, you can speed this up by avoiding duplicate checks.

Honestly this sounds more like a homework question than engineering question so I don't think NoSQL is appropriate.

Here is how you speed it up.

If loop is way too complicated & contains several unnecessary checks.
True is always true so there is no reason to check if it's true.

```
  if (row[0] == experiment)
    exp1 = (row[0] == experiment) && row[7] == data)
    if exp1
      exp1_array.push(row)
    end
  end
```

You are checking `row[0]` twice for same condition. When you remove that you get:

```
  if (row[0] == experiment)
    exp1 = (row[7] == data)
    if exp1
      exp1_array.push(row)
    end
  end
```

This can be further simplified into

```
  if (row[0] == experiment)
    if row[7] == data
      exp1_array.push(row)
    end
  end
```

and this into

```
  if row[0] == experiment && row[7] == data
      exp1_array.push(row)
  end
```

or make it a one-liner

```
  exp1_array.push(row) if row[0] == experiment && row[7] == data
```

End result is

```
CSV.foreach(filepath) do |row|
  exp1_array.push(row) if row[0] == experiment && row[7] == data
end
```

This will be faster because comparing every string to experiment twice is not cheap when repeated large enough number of times.

Now you can use select function to select rows you need for you. This might make it significantly faster because select is (I assume) written in C and thus very fast.

```
exp1_array = CSV.foreach(filepath)
  .select { |row| row[0] == experiment && row[7] == data }
```